# Annotation @Generated used in querydsl broken when using with Java 9, Idea and Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, querydsl

I am implementing querydsl with Spring Boot using IntelliJ Idea. I am using Java 9. My issue is that all my QClasses seems to be broken in the IDE. I have read about the changes in Java 9 and although I am not adding a `module-info.java`, I have read that using the `javax.annotation-api` should get things to work. But it doesn't.
[image]

Also, since I am using Sping, `javax.annotation-api:1.3.2` is already in my classpath
[image]

I have also tried adding the dependency manually in the gradle build, but to no avail. At this point, it seems like I am missing a setting or something. Any help is appreciated.

**N.B.** I am using the querydsl gradle plugin by ewerk. Also I don't want to `--add-modules` although I have tried it and it works. This is because I have read that it isn't future proof so I want to stay away from it.

Comment: Seems there is related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-187250

Comment: Yeah, looks like the exact issue. Then I guess I will have to wait for this to be fixed. Looks like I will have to use the jvm flag in the meantime.